# Login button doesn't redirect to dashboard

Tags: angular, routes

have an issue. Login services check if password wrong or correct, but currently navigation router doesn't work correctly. I'm missing something, can you please point what exactly?

Git: https://github.com/TyroniUA/auth

Function which is responsible for redirection.

```
 AuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
       this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        })
      this.SetUserData(result.user);
    }).catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error)
    })
  }
```

Routing component:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './components/signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './components/signup/signup.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { AuthGuard } from "./shared/guard/auth.guard";
import { SecureInnerPagesGuard } from "./shared/guard/secure-inner-pages.guard";

import { VerifyEmailComponent } from './components/verify-email/verify-email.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/sign-in', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'sign-in', component: SigninComponent, canActivate: [SecureInnerPagesGuard]},
  { path: 'register-user', component: SignupComponent, canActivate: [SecureInnerPagesGuard]},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent, canActivate: [SecureInnerPagesGuard] },
  { path: 'verify-email-address', component: VerifyEmailComponent, canActivate: [SecureInnerPagesGuard] }
]
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**UPD auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from "../../shared/services/auth.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    public router: Router
  ){ }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn !== true) {
      this.router.navigate(['sign-in'])
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: On a sidenote.. Are you sure you need stuff like `this.ngZone.run(() => {}`. edit: you're probably having timing issues. Your `SecureInnerPagesGuard` most likely blocks navigation.

Comment: But if I disable Guard then anybody can access dashboard without login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no problem with your logic of authentication workflow.

But I guess you made mistakes on this.authService.isLoggedIn function. it seems returning false always.
That's why it seems looping the process over again, but didn't actually login.

```
    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn !== true) {
      this.router.navigate(['sign-in'])
    }
```

Could check that part again?

Answer (score 0):

You have set Authgaurd for 'dashboard' route and your are redirecting user to dashboard route even user already logout so either you should remove Authguard for dashboard route or create separate home page for guest user.

Comment: Hi, yes. Problem is with Authguard setup. Updated the original message with Auth script.

But how can I track if user logged out and not entered email + password?

Comment: user logged out and not entered email/password, means? I did not understand question?

Comment: Currently it checks if user logged out. If yes - redirect to signing page. But when user signing it checks again if user logged out. So it's kinda loop.

How to check then if user logged out, but entered email + password and they are valid => redirect to dashboard.

I do not get this AuthGuard clearly currently.

Answer (score 0):

If login responds positive, you need to **update your data/state of you application**
with respect to condition you have used in AuthGuard to prevent Dashboard redirection without login

before you call `this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);`

Hope this helps